# def Palindrome() doesn't return Palyndrom

Tags: python-3.x, function, palindrome

I face the problem and don't know the way to fix it.
Code works good but anyway it reponds that 'message' isn't palyndrom even if it's really palindrom. But when I revise it with one word only it goes.
Thanks!

```
import string


def MultiplePalyndrome():
    isPalyndrome = True
    message = input('Your message\n').lower()
    punct = set(string.punctuation)
    gap = set(string.whitespace)
    message_revis = ''.join(x for x in message if x not in punct or x not in gap)
    i = 0
    while i < len(message_revis) / 2 and isPalyndrome:
        if message_revis[i] != message_revis[len(message_revis) - i - 1]:
            isPalyndrome = False
        i = i + 1
    if isPalyndrome:
        print("It's palyndrome! Yeah.")
    else:
        print("Nope. It's NOT palyndrome!")


MultiplePalyndrome()
```

i really dont know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if x not in punct or x not in gap
```

is always true since every char is *not whitespace* OR *not punctuation*. You probably want:

```
if x not in punct and x not in gap
```

This transforms via [DeMorgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to:

```
if not (x in punct or x in gap)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped really. Especially for DeMorgan's Law

Comment: Cheers =) btw, `str.isalpha` is a useful function which will probably cover all your cases: `... = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, message))`